# Built AOSP, can't run emulator

Tags: android-emulator, aosp, avd-manager

Following the directions to build AOSP, everything seems to go fine.
I run:

```
. ./build/envsetup.sh
lunch sdk_phone_x86_64-userdebug
make
m
```

That seems to go fine.

Then the instructions say simply to run `emulator`.

```
user@hostname:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY$ emulator
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.3.9.0 (build_id 9070145) (CL:N/A)
ERROR   | No AVD specified. Use '@foo' or '-avd foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'

user@hostname:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY$ emulator -list-avds
```

Nothing is listed.  So I feel like the instructions are missing a step? How do I create an AVD?

So, I found some more instructions that say:

```
avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86"
```

But I'm not sure where the `system[...]` came from, but more importantly when I try that:

```
avdmanager: command not found
```

So again, I feel I'm missing a step.

I'm looking for a COMPLETE set of steps, from soup to nuts, to compile AOSP and run the emulator.  I would like to do this from the command line and avoid having to install Android Studio.

Details on my machine:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Comment: You should be able to download command-line tools from [the official Android Developer site](https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools) down below, then download a system image using [`sdkmanager`](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdkmanager), then run the emulator using [`avdmanager`](https://developer.android.com/tools/avdmanager).

Comment: thanks @AndrewT. i'll run with that because it's all i've got, but i really am looking for COMPLETE, WORKING INSTRUCTIONS.  so i go download cmdline-tools, ok i'm smart enough to unzip it, but then what?  do i add the bin to my path?  or do they need to be copied somewhere else? are there any library paths that need to be set?  if so how? etc...

Comment: again @AndrewT. i need COMPLETE instructions.

$ avdmanager

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.